# Reading from file issue

Tags: c, file-io, graph

I am trying to read a graph from file, I got on the first line the nodes, and I made a code that reads the nodes in the vector until the end of the line, then on the second like I got the arcs, in the (%d %d) format. My problem is that when I try to read the nodes, it skips the first number, third, and so on. And I cannot figure out why.
Here is my code:

```
void readGraph() {
    int i=0, j, node1, node2, n,check1, check2,c;
    char nodes[MAXN];
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("data.in","r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening file!");
    }
    else {

       while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {

            if ( c != ' ') {
                fscanf(f, "%d", &(nodes[i]));
                printf("%d, %d\n",i,nodes[i]);
                i++;
            }

            if (c == '\n')
                break;

        }
    }

    while (fscanf(f,"(%d %d)", &node1, &node2)) {

        if ( c != ' ')
            fscanf(f, "(%d %d) ", &node1, &node2);

        if (c == '\n')
            break;

   }
   fclose(f);
}
```

Also, my data.in:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
(1 3) (2 3) (3 4) (3 5) (3 6) (4 6) (5 6)
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, fgetc reads byte by byte, and fscanf("%d") reads 4 bytes at a time, so this could cause some issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {

        if ( c != ' ') {
            fscanf(f, "%d", &(nodes[i]));
            printf("%d, %d\n",i,nodes[i]);
            i++;
        }

        if (c == '\n')
            break;

    }
```

Here you read twice from f (`fgetc(f)` is discarded)

For the arcs (code below) there's also a problem, you test `c` but you're not reading it any more

```
    while (fscanf(f,"(%d %d)", &node1, &node2)) {

        if ( c != ' ')
            fscanf(f, "(%d %d) ", &node1, &node2);

        if (c == '\n')
            break;

   }
```

Comment: So should I replace c with nodes[i], and node1, node 2 respectively?

Comment: There's several ways to do this, for instance read each line with `getline`, then using `sscanf` in your string for the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
void readGraph(void){
    int i = 0, j, node1, node2, n, check1, check2, c;
    int nodes[MAXN];
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("data.in","r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening file!");
        return ;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        if( c == ' ')
            continue;
        else if( c == '\n')
            break;
        else {
            ungetc(c, f);//It is too reading. So Return the character to the stream.
            fscanf(f, "%d", &nodes[i]);
            printf("%d, %d\n", i, nodes[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

    while (2 == fscanf(f,"(%d %d) ", &node1, &node2)) {
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", node1, node2);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: I see the point. Yes, it works now. Though I have one little more issue. I need an n that is the number of nodes and I was thinking to put that on the first line, the second would be the nodes, and third the arcs. If I try to copy the while and modify such that it scans n, it does not work.

Comment: @Yukilikespie try for first line : `fscanf(f, "%d ", &n);`

Comment: Okay, that is weird, first thing that I tried was that, before the while thing. Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution and you can see my c comments:

```
void readGraph() {
    int i=0, j, node1, node2, n,check1, check2,c;
    char nodes[128];
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen("data.in","r");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error in opening file!");
    }
    else {

       while (((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {

            if ( c != ' ') {
                nodes[i] = c;
                /*fscanf(f, "%d", &(nodes[i]));*/ // you loose read c value when you read again without using value
                printf("%d, %c\n",i,nodes[i]);
                i++;
            }

            /*if (c == '\n')
                break;*/ 
            /* You loop 1 extra time */

        }
    }

    while (fscanf(f,"(%d %d)", &node1, &node2)) {

        if ( c != ' ')
            fscanf(f, "(%d %d) ", &node1, &node2);

        if (c == '\n')
            break;

   }
   fclose(f);
}
```